# Administrative recovery control mentions antivirus - error?

Tags: cissp, administration

I am reading through Version 7 of the CISSP study guide and stumbled on a possible error. It mentions - in the administrative controls section - that Recovery is a subset/alternate version of corrective controls and include (various), but also antivirus.

I am not sure that is actually correct, however the errata page on Wiley ([publisher link](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1119042712.html)) does not mention this as an error. Would anyone in the hive on InfoSec give me an explanation as to why it is not an error?

Comment: I guess they mean anti-virus in deep scan mode. You're already infected but you run a deep scan & clean, which is a corrective action.

Comment: Yes that would be a Recovery control, but basic antivirus - either signature based or heuristic guess machine - is purely detection. The deep scan and clean would make sense, I just do not know whether that should be considered the interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one came ahead I tried to leverage another tome in the library.
The "official isc2 guide to the cissp cbk" states that a Recovery Control is intended to reinstate any changes in the access control environment that is caused by an incident, or to offer compensating control in order to return to normal operations.

I argue that antivirus is actually neither, which must mean that an error is to be reported. Sorry for any inconvenience.